# Convert a comma separated string into differents rows in a single query in InfluxDB

Tags: sql, database, influxdb, influxql, csv

I have a table in InfluxDB which, for optimization, contains a field that can either come only as it would be for example "FR204" or it can come in a string concatenated by commas as would be the case with "FR204, FR301".

The fact is that I would like to be able to do exactly what is reflected in this case: https://rstopup.com/convertir-una-cadena-separada-por-comas-en-cada-una-de-las-filas.html

Is it possible to do this in InfluxDB? Thanks.